# How to build native office for mac 2016 application (UI)

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word, ms-office

We build many office application for windows, and it work very natively with office UI but when we came to do same on office for mac we have been lost :(

We need an embedded native Microsoft word for MAC 2016 (better if works with Microsoft word for mac 2011 too) 
*by native we mean to be embedded in word window, not like the VBA forms, like word panels etc

*The most important issue for us is the UI and how it will work like if it was built by Microsoft it self,
*ANY SOLUTION FOR MS-WORD FOR WINDOWS IS NOT WHAT WE ARE LOOKING FOR AT ALL, THE SCOPE IS MICROSOFT WORD BUT FOR MAC 
*The UI we prefer first is something like word native pans such as
*Navigation pane
*Task pane
*Side bar/pan

if this not possible then 2nd option will be 
*Ribbon
if this not possible then 3rd option will be
*Toolbox

We open to use any technology to build this, such as VBA,swift, objective-c whatever provide us with the solution we need,

Any advice??

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, the support for embedding native clients is going the way of the dodo. Everything is moving towards the [Office Web Apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/jj219437(v=office.15)) and embedding that view within applications. It might make sense to review if that allows for the functionality you are looking for based on how it's deployed.